# Generators of $\mathfrak{so}(5)$

Tags: lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

$\newcommand{\bbr}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bbc}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\sof}{\mathsf{SO}(5)}
\newcommand{\msof}{\mathfrak{so}(5)}$
Let $\mathsf{SO}(n):=\{A\in M_n(\bbr)\mid AA^T=I,\det A=1\}$ denote the special orthogonal group and $\mathfrak{so(n)}:=\{A\in M_n(\bbr)\mid A=-A^T\}$ denote the corresponding Lie algebra. It is well known that $\dim\mathfrak{so(n)}=\frac{n(n-1)}2$. In particular, $\msof$ can be generated by $10$ elements of $M_5(\bbr)$ and it is very easy to describe a particular set of generators.

But, I don't understand the description of the generators of $\msof$ given in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.11282.pdf) arXiv paper(section $2.10$). The author considers the following $8\times 8$ real matrices
$$\gamma^i:=\begin{pmatrix}0&e^i\\-e^i&0\\\end{pmatrix},\gamma^4:=\begin{pmatrix}0&I\\I&0\\\end{pmatrix},\gamma^5:=\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\0&I\\\end{pmatrix}$$ where the $e^i$ are $4\times 4$ real matrices given as follows:
    $$e^1=-E_{12}-E_{34},e^2=-E_{13}+E_{24},e^3=-E_{14}-E_{23}.$$
Here, $E_{ij}$ is a $4\times 4$ anti-symmetric matrix with $1$ on the $i$th row and $j$th column. The author claims that the commutators of the above $\gamma$ matrices generate the Lie Algebra of $\sof$. I wonder how? The $\gamma$ matrices are $8\times 8$, whereas the $\msof$ is a subspace of $M_5(\bbr)$. Is there some kind of identification going on(perhaps using the isomorphism $\sof\cong \mathsf{Sp}(2)/\mathbb Z_2$)? I would just mention that the given paper is related to mathematical physics and I'm not much familiar with the Physics conventions.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28535/lie-bracket-for-lie-algebra-of-son-m. Browsing through the net, I found these very interesting notes : https://math.mit.edu/~ebelmont/lie-notes.pdf...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick look at the paper, the author is treating $SO(5)$ as an abstract group, in particular it is not the same as the definition you have given (which I believe is referred to as the "defining representation" of the group). Right before equation (6) on page 2, he remarks that it is "well-known" that $SO(5)$ is isomorphic to the group of unitary $2\times 2$ matrices with quaternionic entries, hence a special type of $8\times 8$ real matrix since the quaternions are $4$-dimensional. And presumably he works with this representation of $SO(5)$ for the remainder of the paper.

Comment: Yes, it will, since now it will appear again as $8\times 8$ real matrices. I don't know what $UH(2)$ is (and did not read that far into the paper) but I will point out that modding out by a finite group does not change the Lie algebra, thus it suffices to find the Lie algebra of $UH(2)$.